# Removing Heroku projects

Tags: heroku

If I login and go to the dashboard in Heroku I am presented with many projects. I would like to remove some/all projects as most of these projects are old. I cannot see a way to remove projects(s) to clean up my dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Select one app, go to Settings, scroll at the bottom and choose

**Delete App**: Deleting your app and its add-ons is irreversible.